# How to check Redshift COPY command performance from AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm working on an application wherein I'll be loading data into **Redshift**.

I want to upload the files to **S3** and use the **COPY** command to load the data into multiple tables.

For every such iteration, I need to load the data into around **20 tables**.

I'm now creating **20 CSV files** for loading data into **20 tables** wherein for every iteration, the **20** created files will be loaded into **20 tables**. And for next iteration, new **20** CSV files will be created and dumped into **Redshift**.

With the current system that I have, each CSV file may contain a maximum of **1000 rows** which should be dumped into tables. Maximum of **20000 rows** for every iteration for **20 tables**.

I wanted to improve the performance even more. I've gone through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-S3.html

At this point, I'm not sure how long it's gonna take for 1 file to load into 1 Redshift table. Is it really worthy to split every file into multiple files and load them parallelly?

Is there any source or calculator to give an approximate performance metrics of data loading into **Redshift** tables based on number of columns and rows so that I can decide whether to go ahead with splitting files even before moving to **Redshift**.

Comment: What is your actual concern? Do you need the files loaded within a particular timeframe? How often are you doing this load? (Once per day, every hour, every minute?) You say that you want to improve performance, but what is your current performance to load a simple table? If you want to 'improve' performance, then you should start by measuring current performance. A file with 1000 rows is very small for Redshift.

Comment: I'll be loading files at a rate of 10 iterations per minute. I haven't even tested the current performance. I'm just thinking if it's even worthy to divide the files into multiple files for processing or just proceed with single file as it's just max of 1000 rows per file which @Nathan clarified.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading files at a rate of 10 iterations per minute"? Are you wanting to load all 20 tables at a rate of 10 times every minute? If so, this does not sound like a feasible way to use Redshift.

Comment: Yes. I'll be creating 20 new files per iteration and inserting them into Redshift tables.

Comment: where you able to find a performant solution?

Comment: Nope. We left that work completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also read through the recommendations in the Load Data - Best Practices guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html

Regarding the number of files and loading data in parallel, the recommendations are:

- Loading data from a single file forces Redshift to perform a
  serialized load, which is much slower than a parallel load.
- Load data files should be split so that the files are about equal size,
  between 1 MB and 1 GB after compression. For optimum parallelism, the ideal size is between 1 MB and 125 MB after compression.
- The number of files should be a multiple of the number of slices in your
  cluster.

That last point is significant for achieving maximum throughput - if you have 8 nodes then you want n*8 files e.g. 16, 32, 64 ... this is so all nodes are doing maximum work in parallel.

That said, 20,000 rows is such a small amount of data in Redshift terms I'm not sure any further optimisations would make much significant difference to the speed of your process as it stands currently.

Comment: And I also have a requirement to load all those files specific to an iteration on a single node.